# Shell Script Count String Occurrence

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am working on a project and need help figuring out how to do a task. 
I am going to be given a log file, and I need to parse through and count the amount of times something occurs at a certain minute.

For example, if I have a txt file:

```
Line 3: 0606 221241  successfully copied to **
Line 5: 0606 221242  successfully copied to **
Line 7: 0606 221242  successfully copied to **
Line 9: 0606 221342  successfully copied to **
```

I want to know how many times something was successfully copied at 2212
So far, I have the following code seperating only lines that have been successful copied and getting the dates seperate...

```
grep "successfully copied to" Text.log >> Success.txt
awk '{print ($1,  $2)}' Success.txt > datesAndTimes.txt
```

This gives me

```
0606 221241
0606 221242
0606 221242
0606 221243
```

For some reason, I am having trouble figuring out how to count the amount of times  each specific time (ex. 0606 2212) occurs. occurs. 
I only need the minutes, not the seconds (the last two digits of the second column)
Eventually I want a log/txt file that says:

```
0606 2212 3
0606 2213 1
```

and so on....

If any one has any ideas, I'm having a bit of a brain fart. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might be interested in `uniq -c`.

Comment: @squiguy that could work! I couldn't think of the command and/or the search I needed to find it. Any advice on how to get the substring of just the first 4 characters of the second column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this in awk one liner:

```
awk '{mm=substr($4, 1, 4); cnt[$3 " " mm]++} END{for(a in cnt) print a " " cnt[a]}' Text.log
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/w2h64d

Comment: would you mind explaining it a bit to me? I am newer to script and would like to learn instead of just copying!

Comment: sure I can explain. First I get 4 digits of `$4` (timestamp) that constituted minute part. Then I create and increment an associative array `cnt` with the key `$3 " " mm` e.g. `0606 2212`. Once END of file is reached this array is printed on stdout.

Comment: thank you, I understand. Is there anyway to order it in its original order? because it is all out of order this way

Comment: @user1998581, pipe the output into `sort -nk1,2`

Comment: we can get rid of the grep call too: `awk '/successfully copied to/ {mn=...`

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks, I thought all the lines in input file contain `successfully copied to` text :P

Comment: @anubhava in my example they did but in my actual task they do not! Thank you so much!

Comment: @glennjackman I tried using sort but it did not work! Where would you put that in your code?

Comment: You can use: `awk '{mm=substr($4, 1, 4); cnt[$3 " " mm]++} END{for (a in cnt) print a " " cnt[a]}' x | sort -nk1,2`

Comment: @anubhava that sorts the list, but stops my output from saying how many times it occurred....

Comment: `sort -nk1,2` is for sorting the list only, it cannot mask the 3rd column from stdout. I have provided you a demo on ideone.com and if you can reproduce your problem there and provide me a link, I will sure help you out.

Comment: The list that is being input is already sorted....  once it the array is processed and printed, it somehow gets out of order. Is there a way to sort the array?

Comment: Yes awk has sort functions too: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html#Array-Sorting-Functions

Comment: okay thank you... last question I promise! Instead of printing, can I write my output to a txt file? I tried to do it the way I know using `echo stuff >> textfile` instead of print but it gave me syntax error.

Comment: can you try: `awk '{mm=substr($4, 1, 4); cnt[$3 " " mm]++} END{for(a in cnt) print a " " cnt[a]}' Text.log > textfile`